# Building FFMpeg for Android NDK gives me .a instead of .so files

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm a Mac user. I followed this tutorial : http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ to build FFMpeg for Android using NDK

I'm using *FFMpeg 2.1* and *NDK r9*.

Here is my `build_android.sh` file in my *FFMepg* folder which is in my `$NDK/sources` folder :

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=$HOME/Desktop/adt/android-ndk
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

Evrything is compiling fine but at the end I get `.a` files whereas in the tutorial I should get `.so` files.

What is wrong with what I did ? The only thing that changes is :

```
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
```

which is :

```
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `make` that comes with NDK:

```
...
$NDK/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/make clean
$NDK/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/make
$NDK/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/make install
```

BTW, you can put `ffmpeg` sources anywhere, no need to keep it under `NDK/sources`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach but not suceeded. 
Change to `--disable-shared` and `enable-static`

After your make install add following

```
$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$SYSROOT/usr/lib -L$SYSROOT/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog -lx264  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $TOOLCHAIN/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
```

This worked for me! This approach is building .a and linking all .a to .so file. Change `libffmpeg.so` to any name you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the following errors when executing the 2 last commands : /path/to/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: ,noexecstack: unknown -z option
/path/to/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: use the --help option for usage information

Comment: use `path/to/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm‌​-linux-androideabi-ld --help`. check for `-z,noexecstack`. if it's not there, try removing it. Actually i built on linux-32bit ubunthu. i am not worked on any darwin machine. Also suggest you to use ndk 32 bit release if you are on darwin-32bit os. Because using both 32bit+64bit ndk built on my linux-32bit os causes many errors that solved when using 32 bit built ndk